# Avoid using instanceOf in observer method

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

I have the following system in Java:

```
public class Human {
     public void drown(Animal animal) {
          if (animal instanceOf Fish) {
              return;
          } else {
              animal.die();
          }
     }
}

public abstract class LandAnimal extends Animal{...}
public class Tiger extends LandAnimal{...}

public abstract class Fish extends Animal {...}
public class Trout extends Fish {...}
```

I have thought of adding a method

```
public abstract boolean drownable() {...}
```

in class Animal but I don't have access to the code of Animal class.
As I know the use of instanceOf is considered bad OOP practice. How do I avoid the use of instanceOf in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Why not an abstract `.drowned()` method on `Animal`? Methods _can_ do nothing

Comment: Are you looking for Visitor pattern ?

Comment: drowning animals is uncool =(

Comment: Wow is the code in `Human#drown` a complicated way to write `if (!(animal instanceof Fish)) { animal.drown(); }` ;-)

Comment: The downvote seems harsh.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder bah, there are also people which `else` after they `return`

Answer (score 2):

The `drown()` method in `Human` should be (by the way, why do humans want to drown animals?):

```
 public void drown(Animal animal) {
      animal.drown();
 }
```

And each `Animal` will know what to do, for example:

```
// in class Tiger
public void drown() {
    die();
}

// in class Fish
public void drown() {
    // do nothing, fish can't drown
}
```

Comment: +1, but this really only makes sense if `Animal#drown` is renamed. `Animal#immerseInWater` or some such. Since fish can't drown in water.

Comment: The `return;` in `Fish` is redundant :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm assuming that all animals implement the same interface, which includes the `drown()` method

Answer (score 2):

You would declare `Animal.drown()` and override it in `Fish`, containing the appropriate 'kill code' :).
So you'd just need to call `drown()` on each animal and each instance will behave according to its type specific method implementation.

```
public class Human {
     public void drown(Animal animal) {
         animal.drown();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods can be overloaded based on their arguments. You can have two different methods:

```
public void drown(Fish f) {
  return;
}

public void drown(LandAnimal a) {
  a.drown();
}
```

However, it should be noted that this makes determining whether some animal will drown the responsibility of the `Human` class, which, as other answers show, is arguable.